# css validator parse error wildcard / asterisk and before after

Tags: css, css-selectors

On https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri+with_options this renders a Parse error:

`*, *:before, *:after{box-sizing:border-box;}`

What am I doing wrong, if I want to apply this rule to all elements within html? Any wildcard/asterisk use seems to be erroneous. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you validating it? It validates just fine for me as CSS2.1 (when you remove the box-sizing declaration) and CSS3+SVG. Not that you should ever use Jigsaw in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

example on tailwindcss doc

`In order to make it easy to add a border by simply adding the border class, Tailwind overrides the default border styles for all elements with the following rules:`

```
*,
::before,
::after {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: theme('borderColor.default', currentColor);
}
```

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#border-styles-are-reset-globally